# How to add LIKE to this Eloquent query

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I'm working with Laravel 5.8 and I have this method:

```
public function getCourseDefinition()
    {
        $course_definition = DB::table('getCourseDefinition');
         
        if (request()->has('cod_title') && request('cod_title'))
            $course_definition = $course_definition->whereRaw("cod_title = ?", [request('cod_title')]);
    }
```

So it basically checks if the request contains `cod_title`, then searches for that particular `request('cod_title')`.

But now I need to add **`LIKE`** for returning similar results based on the entered input.

So I tried this instead:

```
$course_definition = $course_definition->whereRaw("cod_title = ?", 'LIKE', [request('cod_title')]);
```

But got this error:

### **Array to string conversion**

So whats going wrong here?

How can I add `LIKE` to this search query?

Answer (score 1):

[`whereRaw`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#whereraw-orwhereraw) only takes two arguments.

Define like this

```
$course_definition = $course_definition->whereRaw("cod_title LIKE ?", ['%' . request('cod_title') . '%']);
```

---

**From the Laravel Docs**

> The `whereRaw` and `orWhereRaw` methods can be used to ***inject a raw "where" clause into your query***. These methods ***accept an optional array of bindings as their second*** argument

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `where` eloquent method like so:

```
public function getCourseDefinition()
{
   $course_definition = DB::table('getCourseDefinition')
   ->when(request()->has('cod_title') && request('cod_title'), function($query){
     $query->where('cod_title', 'like', '%'.request('cod_title').'%');
   })
   ..// ;
}
```